# Solving Heat Equation with Transport Term

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, transport-equation

I'd like to solve this equation:

$$
u_t  = u_{xx} + u_x 
$$
for $t>0$ with initial condition:
$$
u(0,x) = \cos (2 \pi x)
$$
And $1$-periodic, i.e we have that $u(t,x) = u(t,x+1).$
I was going to solve it using separation of variables, but I was thinking another way, namely solving it using a fourier series. I.e, first I assume that $u$ has fourier series expansion:
$$
u(t,x) = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} a_k(t)e^{2\pi ikx}
$$
Now, I would like to differentiate the coefficients in the series and set them equal to each other. Something akin to:
$$
a_k'(t) = 2\pi ike^{2\pi i k x} ak(t) + (2 \pi ik )^2 ak(t) e^{2 \pi i k x}
$$
And then solve for $ak(t)$. Two questions: 1) is this method valid? I.e is it true that the series are equal if and only if the coefficients are? 2) If I can use this method, how do I solve the ODE for $a_k(t)$? Apologies if this is particularly obvious, I have never taken an ODEs class

Comment: Your method works, but your governing equation seems to observe some typos. It should be $a_k'e^{2\pi ikx}=2\pi ika_ke^{2\pi ikx}+\left(2\pi ik\right)^2a_ke^{2\pi ikx}$. Since $\left\{e^{2\pi ikx}\right\}_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}$ forms an orthonormal basis, this equation implies that the coefficient in front of each $e^{2\pi ikx}$ must vanish, which yields $a_k'=2\pi ika_k+\left(2\pi ik\right)^2a_k$. This is no more than an ODE now.

Comment: Yes this method should work - in fact I suspect it is the same solution you'd get if you did do separation of variables - you'd get a term in $t$ and a term in $x$ which looks like that fourier term (since it must be $1$ periodic), and then to get a general solution, a general linear combination would be taken (the sum)

Comment: @hypernova Thank you for your explanation. Just to clarify, the coefficients vanish because if we have $\sum (a_k - b_k)e_k = 0$ where $e_k$ forms a (Schauder?) basis (for what space? sufficiently smooth periodic functions) then it follows by linear independence that $a_k = b_k$.

Comment: @qbert my professor gave this problem on a review sheet for a midterm. He said it contained questions from prior exams. Perhaps you took the same class with the same professor?

Comment: @rubikscube09 looking at your previous questions, my suspicion is yes :)

Comment: @rubikscube09: It is a Schauder basis for general $L^p([0,1])$ ($p>1$, typically $p=2$ for a Hilbert space). You may let $x\to x/L$ to get it to $L^p([0,L])$ as well. This is why, for mathematical rigor, you need to check what you get from the equations is indeed a solution (e.g., using dominate convergence theorem to show that $\partial_t$, $\partial_x^m$ and $\sum_{j\in\mathbb{Z}}$ are commutative, using absolute convergence to show that terms in this series could be rearranged so that your governing equation makes sense, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes this method is valid (under the same hypothesis as for the usual heat equation).
2. Your ODE for $a_k$ should be:
   $$a_k'(t)=2i \pi k a_k(t)+(2i \pi k)^2 a_k(t)=(-4 \pi k^2+2i \pi k)a_k(t)$$
   so:
   $$a_k(t)=e^{(-4 \pi k^2+2i \pi k) t} a_k(0)$$

Comment: Thank you. The above solution to the ODE is simply solving the ODE $f ' = f$ right? Or some derivative of it? Apologies for the rather elementary questions, although I am taking PDE I have not taken ODE.

Comment: Yes it is simply an ODE such as $f'=\lambda f$.